# Security vulnerability:exe or other malicious must not upload by changing their header and ext pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpg,jpeg,png etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

We have allowed to upload .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx and images like .jpg, .jpeg, .png files in ASP.net MVC 5 everything working fine but my security team raised security vulnerability. Security team changing the malicious file extension as allowed extensions and changing header with supporting file type header by tool before server hit and file get uploaded on server.
We are finding the solution in asp.net MVC C# but didn't get solution to stop uploading malicious file on server through my asp.net MVC C# application.

We have used following code and also used winista mime detect but unable to get proper solution. They are not returning proper mime type.

```
public class urlmonMimeDetect
    {
        [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
            System.UInt32 pBC,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
            System.UInt32 cbSize,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
            System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
            out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
            System.UInt32 dwReserverd
        );

        public static string GetMimeFromFile(Stream fs)
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);

            try
            {
                System.UInt32 mimetype;
                FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
                System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
                string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
                return mime;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "unknown/unknown";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an inherently flawed approach to trying to stop "malicious files" since an attacker could just upload a malicious file of an allowed file type -- *all* of the extensions you name have been used to exploit systems based on bugs in the parsers for them (and in the case of .docx, macro support). If you want a solid solution to this, use a commercial package/service like a malware scanner to actually scan files regardless of what file type they are, or are presented to be.

Comment: What's more, you should be cognizant of what your actual attack vectors are. Let's say someone uploads an executable by renaming it -- then what? It won't do anything on its own. Who would ultimately be expected to rename the file back and run it? Are these files going to be downloaded again by other end users? If those users are in the habit of treating untrusted files this way, you have bigger problems than uploads in your website.

Comment: Obviously these uploaded files get download too

Comment: That's not at all that obvious -- I've worked on plenty of systems where the uploaded files get processed by the backend system, and only the results of that processing ever end up with end users, not the original files. So it's good to mention it!